# Why can pointers be NULL

Tags: c++, c, pointers, null

In C or C++, isn't NULL just the constant integer 0? Why are we allowed to assign some pointer to the value NULL if it a constant integer? Wouldn't a compiler say that the two types don't match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpretation of the constant `0` depends on the context. If it's being used in a context where a number is required, it's the number zero. If it's being used in a context where a pointer is required, it's treated as a null pointer. So if you have the code:

```
int n = 0; // assigns zero
int *p = 0; // assigns null pointer
somefunc((char *)0); // passes null pointer to the function
```

In C, the macro `NULL` is permitted to expand into either an integer constant `0` or such a constant cast to `void *`. In C++ pre-11, it can expand into either an integer constant that evaluates to `0`. In C++-11 it can expand into an integer literal with value `0` or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` (e.g. `nullptr`).

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL for the C++ description, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL for the C description.

Comment: In C++, it's allowed to expand to any null pointer constant, including `nullptr`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen but in C++ it's *not* allowed to be `(void*)0` since C++ doesn't do implicit conversion of `void*` like C does.

Comment: The question was about the definition of NULL.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure, wasn't disputing that.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL says it must be an integer literal or a value of type `std::nullptr_t`. Is `(void*)0` one of those?

Comment: @Barmar No, but `nullptr` is.

Comment: The question is mainly about why `0` is allowed, not the other possibilities. But I updated my answer to include them.

Comment: @Barmar `0` when assigned to a pointer variable assigns the _"null-pointer-value"_ to the pointer.  This _"null-pointer-value"_ does not have to assign the value zero to the pointer it can assign a platform specific value that indicates that the pointer hold the null value.

Comment: @RichardCritten Where did I say it assigns the value zero to the pointer?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1. A type can have a "special", out-of-band, exceptional value.  For example, floating-point numbers have the value `NaN`.  And pointers have a special, not-a-valid-pointer value, the null pointer.
2. What's the name of the null pointer?  In C, for better or worse, its name is `0`.  (It would avoid all kinds of confusion if its name were a separate keyword like `null` or `nil`, but that's not the way the language definition came out.)

But yes, you're right, the ability to assign the constant `0` to a pointer variable is a special case, enshrined in the language definition.

Comment: So then is nullptr literally just memory location "0"? And also, my professor said that for functions that return a pointer to an element in an array, more and more people are assigning the pointer to the element after the last one in an array if some condition is not met, rather than assigning the pointer to NULL or nullptr. Is that actually true?

Comment: @HowardWang It is not necessarily memory location 0.  But for every followon question you can imagine, see the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html).

Comment: @HowardWang modern C++ uses iterators that are similar in concept to pointers. All the standard library functions take two iterators to define a range, with the second one pointing to one-after the last valid element. Returning a "not found" value from these functions means returning the end iterator. That's probably exerting some influence on how pointers are used.

Answer (score 1):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3     An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.<sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>66) The macro NULL is defined in <stddef.h> (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.</sup>

*[C 2011 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*

A literal `0` in a pointer context is treated specially by the compiler, and is understood to be the null pointer constant.  In the context of your source code, it behaves like any other zero-valued expression.

However, once your code is translated to machine code, all occurrences of the null pointer constant will be replaced with whatever value the underlying platform uses to represent a well-defined *invalid* pointer value, whether that’s `0` or `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: While the standard allows the possibility of null pointers that aren't physically all zero-bits, I'm not aware of any architectures that work that way. It's just easier and more efficient to use the literal bit pattern of zero.

Comment: @MarkRansom -- I have heard tales of ancient systems with null pointers which were not all bits zero.